# CSS & JQuery browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been working on browser compatibility. Unfortunately, when I first designed my site, I desigend the CSS aesthetically for Firefox only. Now I'm having all sorts of trouble trying to get it to look good in the other major browsers. However, when I fix the CSS positioning such as floating a box object to the right, IE8 forces it left. I checked my code on W3C and it's okay semantically. I use little to no javascript. It's a portfolio website. The screensize shifts everything around no matter what browser, yet there is no perfect CSS for this so how does one get things to stay in place? I'm not too familiar with JQuery, but this seems to be the closest I can get to an answer. Where would I plug this into my site to see if this works?

Comment: You did not show us your `<code>`. And even with code the Q would be confusing.

Comment: @A.D. Sorry. I'm having positioning issues with CSS. I downloaded JQuery thinking that it would calculate the screen size of different users for me, to fix the CSS accordingly. (Does this even exist?) Anyway, I suppose I have to keep messing with the positioning to get it as close as possible in all browsers.

Comment: If you want a clear answer you'll have to post some code that is not doing what you expect it to do, then hopefully someone can spot an error or suggest a better way to solve your problem - jQuery in itself does not automatically fix all CSS positioning issues.

Comment: @Kokodoko Here is my html and css code in entirety for my homepage. 

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DtqlfCGU9L

Comment: I would like it all centered